# Jupyter: An error occurred while creating a new notebook

Tags: 18.04, anaconda, jupyter

I have ununtu 18.04.1 installed as well as the anaconda 4.5.8.

After typing:

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

I get the standard jupyter homepage.

But when I try to click New/Notebook/Python3 I get the following error:

```
Creating Notebook Failed>An error occurred while creating a new notebook>Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
```

How can I fix this?

When I type anaconda navigator into terminal the GUI below starts. I can then start s jypter notebook that works by simply clicking on the jupyter notebook tab.

[image]

However I can't see the anaconda prompt anywhere neither the GUI above on in the original terminal session?

```
desktop:~$ cd /Projects/jupyter-notebook
desktop:/Projects/jupyter-notebook$ anaconda-navigator
```

It's not possible to type anything in this terminal session while anaconda navigator is still running!

Comment: If you are running Python3 in Anaconda then Anaconda doesn't know about the path to Jupyter notebook unless you either installed Jupyter from Anaconda or added the path to Jupyter to Anaconda.

Comment: When i look at the list of packages in anaconda it includes jupyter 1.0.0  but when I type jupyter version it says 4.4.0 so it would seem that I am not using the anaconda version. How can I  ensure that I start the anaconda version?

Comment: What results do you get when you try to start Jupyter from the Anaconda prompt instead of from the default terminal shell? You can start Anaconda Navigator by opening a terminal window and running the command `anaconda-navigator`. The command to start Jupyter from the Anaconda prompt is `jupyter-notebook`

Comment: OK if I start Anaconda Navigator and click on Jupyter notebook it works! But I's like to be able to do it all from the command line. How do I start the anaconda prompt?

Comment: You get the Anaconda prompt when you start Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the terminal and start Anaconda Navigator with the following command:

   ```
   anaconda-navigator
   ```
2. In Ananconda Navigator select *Environments* (in left pane) -> *Python35* -> *Open Terminal*.
3. Click *Open Terminal* and run the following command to start Jupyter Notebook:

   ```
   jupyter-notebook
   ```

   This command starts the Jupyter that is installed in Anaconda, so the Python 3 that is installed in Anaconda is able to recognize it.

Comment: When I type anaconda-navigator (AN) it starts the AN GUI and I'm able to start Jupyter (that works) by clicking on the launch Jupyter tab. I can't see the Anaconda-prompt though? Should I see it in the terminal or in AN GUI? Right now I can't see it anywhere?

Comment: see updated question above

Comment: OK so it's not possible to start it all from terminal? You have to open anaconda-navigator and wither click on the icon or open anaconda terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem and solved it very simply following these steps:

1. Close all Jupyter Notebook tabs on the web browser.
2. Terminate all Jupyter processes in the terminal.
3. Open a new Jupyter Notebook.